# Flutter app crashing without exception when calling FacebookAuth.instance.login()

Tags: firebase, flutter, facebook-login

I've followed the tutorial for implementing the Facebook Login from

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/social/

Which is the official documentation, my function is literally just:

```
facebookLogin() async
  {
    final LoginResult loginResult = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();    // final OAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential = FacebookAuthProvider.credential(loginResult.accessToken!.token);
    // var credentials = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
}
```

I've commented the following function to isolate the problem.

On the console i get the following:

```
Performing hot reload...                                                
Reloaded 1 of 1031 libraries in 908ms.
Lost connection to device.
```

And no exceptions nor errors.

Has anyone faced the same problem before?

I'm using:

flutter_facebook_auth: ^4.1.1
firebase_core: ^1.13.1
firebase_auth: ^3.3.9

In my pubspec.yaml

Is there any way to debug this problem further and find the problem?

Comment: Any updates on this? I faced similar issue - it started to crash out of nowhere...

Answer (score 1):

It can be an issue with info.plist configuration for flutter deep-linking.
Did you setup it for your app?
https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/navigation/deep-linking

to be more specific you should have only one CFBundleURLTypes section in your info.plist

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure that you **followed** the **setup steps one by one**, and they are:

1. Ensure the "Facebook" sign-in provider is enabled on the Firebase Console. **with the Facebook App ID and Secret set**
2. **follow the steps in the plugin** (flutter_facebook_auth) documentation to **ensure that both the Android & iOS Facebook SDKs have been initialized correctly**

Please note that firebase flutterfire uses: `flutter_facebook_auth: '^3.5.0'` in their documentation and the latest version of that package `4.1.1` untill this day (3/4/2022)

Comment: I forgot to mention that it was working, it stopped working without any modifications. Also, is there no way to debug this 'crash'?

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Here is how I solved.

In **Info.plist**, I had 2 sessions called "CFBundleURLTypes", one for Facebook Login, and another one for Google login. **Apparently you can only have one CFBundleURLTypes session**.

So the solution was to **merge everything into a single CFBundleURLTypes session**.