# Flutter app crashes if FacebookAppID is present in info.plist

Tags: flutter, facebook-authentication

after migrating to flutter 3.0.5 my app started crash if FacebookAppID is present in info.plist. If i comment it out everythink works fine.
Any ideas why?

I am using  flutter_facebook_auth: ^4.4.1

there is crash report:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kxoyb8FcZCX54MjND6aYjjt6nnFkJpZV/view?usp=sharing

no logs apart these:

```
executing: /usr/bin/plutil -convert xml1 -o - /Users/vytautaspranskunas/Desktop/Development/senioassist-mobile/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist
[   +8 ms] Exit code 0 from: /usr/bin/plutil -convert xml1 -o - /Users/vytautaspranskunas/Desktop/Development/senioassist-mobile/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app/Info.plist
[        ] <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
           <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
           <plist version="1.0">
           <dict>
            <key>BuildMachineOSBuild</key>
            <string>21F79</string>
            <key>CADisableMinimumFrameDurationOnPhone</key>
            <true/>
            <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
            <string>en</string>
            <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
            <string>Senio Assist</string>
            <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
            <string>Runner</string>
            <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
            <dict>
                <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>AppIcon60x60</string>
                    </array>
                    <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
                    <string>AppIcon</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
            <dict>
<key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
                <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>AppIcon60x60</string>
                        <string>AppIcon76x76</string>
                    </array>
                    <key>CFBundleIconName</key>
                    <string>AppIcon</string>
                </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
            <string>-----</string>
            <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
            <string>6.0</string>
            <key>CFBundleName</key>
            <string>senio_assist</string>
            <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
            <string>APPL</string>
            <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
            <string>99.99.99</string>
            <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
            <string>????</string>
            <key>CFBundleSupportedPlatforms</key>
            <array>
                <string>iPhoneSimulator</string>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                    <string>Editor</string>
                    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>------</string>
                    </array>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                    <string>Editor</string>
                    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
                    <string>3ds.stripesdk.io</string>
                    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>stripesdk</string>
</array>
                </dict>
                <dict>
                    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
                    <string>Editor</string>
                    <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
                    <string>com.senio.assist</string>
                    <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
                    <array>
                        <string>-----</string>
                    </array>
                </dict>
            </array>
            <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
            <string>99</string>
            <key>DTCompiler</key>
            <string>com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0</string>
            <key>DTPlatformBuild</key>
            <string>19C51</string>
            <key>DTPlatformName</key>
            <string>iphonesimulator</string>
            <key>DTPlatformVersion</key>
            <string>15.2</string>
            <key>DTSDKBuild</key>
            <string>19C51</string>
            <key>DTSDKName</key>
            <string>iphonesimulator15.2</string>
            <key>DTXcode</key>
            <string>1321</string>
            <key>DTXcodeBuild</key>
            <string>13C100</string>
            <key>FacebookAppID</key>
            <string>----</string>
            <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
            <string>-----</string>
            <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
            <false/>
            <key>FirebaseDynamicLinksCustomDomains</key>
            <array>
                <string>----</string>
            </array>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fbapi</string>
                <string>fbapi20130214</string>
                <string>fbapi20130410</string>
                <string>fbapi20130702</string>
                <string>fbapi20131010</string>
                <string>fbapi20131219</string>
                <string>fbapi20140410</string>
                <string>fbapi20140116</string>
                <string>fbapi20150313</string>
                <string>fbapi20150629</string>
                <string>fbapi20160328</string>
                <string>fbauth</string>
                <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
                <string>fbauth2</string>
                <string>fbshareextension</string>
                <string>itms-beta</string>
                <string>itms</string>
            </array>
            <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
            <true/>
            <key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
            <string>11.0</string>
            <key>NSBonjourServices</key>
            <array>
                <string>_dartobservatory._tcp</string>
            </array>
            <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Will allow to attach photos to request and complete identity check</string>
            <key>NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Allow Flutter tools on your computer to connect and debug your application. This prompt will not appear on release builds.</string>
            <key>NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
            <string>In order to find closes service providers</string>
            <key>NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
            <string>In order to find closes service providers</string>
            <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
            <string>In order to find closes service providers</string>
            <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
            <string>Will allow to attach images to request and complete identity check</string>
            <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
<array>
                <string>fetch</string>
                <string>remote-notification</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
            <array>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <integer>2</integer>
            </array>
            <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
            <string>LaunchScreen</string>
            <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
            <string>Main</string>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
            </array>
            <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
            <array>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
            <false/>
            <key>io.flutter.embedded_views_preview</key>
            <true/>
           </dict>
           </plist>
```

Comment: Are there any error msgs in the console?

Comment: updated original answer with logs

Comment: Looks like there is a similar situation here, does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71343379/flutter-app-crashing-without-exception-when-calling-facebookauth-instance-login

Comment: No it did ot help. It also started to crash out of the sudden...

Answer (score 0):

There was new property introduced: FacebookClientToken which was missing and without it app was crashing